# On existence of composition of functions

Tags: function-and-relation-composition

Let $f: A \rightarrow B$ and $g: B \rightarrow C$ be two functions.
Then $g \circ f$ is clearly defined $\forall a \in A$ but what about $f \circ g$, do we take it as undefined, given that A and C are disjoint? What if A and C are not disjoint?

Since domain of $g$ is the same as the   codomain of $f$ hence $g \circ f$ exists $\forall a \in A$.

What I think:
If A and C are disjoint sets, then $f(c)$ is not defined, since $c\in C$ is not in the domain of $f$

Am I missing something?

Comment: your logic is sound.

Comment: I think a better way to phrase this is that $f(c)$ is not defined, since $c\in C$ is not in the domain of $f$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a strict definition for composition:

If $f: A \to B$, $g: C \to D$ are functions, the composition $f \circ g$ is the function $C \to B$ given by $c \mapsto g(c) \mapsto f(g(c))$, which is well defined if and only if $g(c) \in A$.

So indeed your intuition is right.